# Placing Adobe pdf into Axure

Tags: tools, axure, pdf

Is there a way to place Adobe assets into Axure? I am hoping to place an InDesign-generated pdf into Axure, but placing an indesign or illustrator file directly would be great too.. However, I cannot figure out how I can import these assets in Axure.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question will get closed as it has nothing to do with UX and is product specific. A better place to ask this would be in the axure forums

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Axure and not specific to UX

Comment: (Though Axure is pretty much specific to UX)

Comment: I posted here because Axure is a tool with which to design User Experiences. In the same way that [Posts concerning Adobe products and other tools dominate a large portion of Graphic Design StackExchange](http://imgur.com/09u2n8u), I figured tools related to UX Design would be relevant here.

Comment: @NickBewley each SE tends to enforce the 'tools' rule in different ways. UX tends to avoid them altogether. GD allows them to a greater extent. (I'm a fan of allowing tools questions, as most UX tools are very UX-centric, but that's just one person's opinion...)

Comment: Being a tool used by UX people doesn't make it a UX question. It's not about User Experience, it's about how to use a particular tool. To take it to the extreme example; We wouldn't accept questions like 'Should I drive at 20 or 40 miles an hour in order to get to my UX Designer job faster' or 'What is the best way to sharpen my pencils so I can draw some wireframes'. Just because you use a tool as part of a UX job, that doesn't mean it's a User Experience question.

Comment: Seemed to have relevance based on the relation of other stack exchange forums to the tools used to produce said things. If that's not the case, my mistake

Comment: @NickBewley: You're not the only one who has, or does think they should be allowed. It's been [discussed on our meta site](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/should-tool-related-questions-be-on-topic) several times in the past.

Comment: @NickBewley I would encourage you to add your thoughts to the linked meta post.  The ultimate question is whether the UX site is better off being exceptionally narrow in focus or if a broader perspective is best.

Comment: Yes, please do chime in on that conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Axure ultimately produces HTML. There's no practical way to embed PDFs into a web page (you can, but it's ugly and somewhat pointless given the intent of Axure's HTML).

What I tend to do is open what I need in preview (I'm on a mac) then just do selective screen shots of the parts I want to put into Axure and then just paste them directly into my Axure file as images.

Comment: Are there any other wireframing tools that will allow the import of pdf's? Thanks for your ideas..

Comment: Depends on what you need/want. AI and Inkscape can both import PDFs, and both are suitable for wireframing. But tools that are meant to create HTML prototypes likely won't have PDF import as an option due to the nature of the medium.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no - importing only works with other RP files or RD-LIB (library files). There is nothing on the forums either regarding this.

[image]

Comment: Note the OP is talking about placing the PDF on the page, rather than importing it as an Axure file. The answer is still the same (you can't) but is a slightly different scenario.